# how get value of constant in system linear equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: e]

i tried to get a value of the constant **a**  but can't

Comment: This is close to trivial. What happens if you subtract the first equation from twice the second equation?

Comment: get nothing "a" is unknown value

Comment: If you do as I wrote you will get the equation $(2a+5)y = -1$. There is **exactly** one value of $a$ for which there is no $y$ satisfying the equation.

Comment: a = -2.5 where equation have no solution ... Thanks to all

Comment: Please take the time to enter key parts of your question—in this case, basically all of it—as text instead of pasting pictures. Your question should be comprehensible without the images, which are neither searchable nor accessible to screen readers. See [this section](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992) of [How To Ask A Good Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/265466). I’d bet that it would’ve taken less time to type in those couple of sentences than it did to take the picture, crop it and upload it.

Comment: thanks for advice <3 ...  in next time i will explain and show my trying to answer As much as I can and thank you again for your interest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** there will be no solution in the event that the two lines are parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the lower equation by $2$ and subtract it from the first to get $-(5+2a)y = 1,$ which has no solution when $a=-\frac{5}{2}$ (this is equivalent to finding the intersection of two parallel lines).